# Disable grey "is now online/offline" messages in iChat

Tags: mac, ichat

When using iChat, grey messages saying "so-and-so is now online" and "so-and-so is now offline" are displayed in the chat window. Is there any way to suppress these messages? When they crop up too often they make it hard to read the chat messages themselves.